# Two distinct planes in a projective space intersect in a line?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

I see from another post 'Can two planes intersect in a point?' that planes in Euclidean spaces of dimension 4 or more can intersect in a single point.  How does this work in projective spaces?  Can 2 distinct non-skew planes intersect in a point?  Since any projective space that contains such planes necessarily has dimension at least 4, and is thus Desarguesian, it seems to me that such planes can exist if and only if there exist 2 3-dimensional subspaces of a 5-dimensional vector space (over a division ring) that intersect in a line.  I have a mental block on this problem - any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: In projective spaces everything behaves very well. Are you familiar with Grassmann's formula for dimensions? $$\dim (V+W)+ \dim (V \cap W) = \dim V + \dim W$$ is all you need. Note that in affine spaces this is not true.

Comment: Thanks Crostul!  I know the formula, but I cannot quite see how to use the dimension formula to rule out the existence of such planes.  Would not the formula be consistent with their existence, so long as the subspace that they generate has dimension 4?  Sorry, I know that I am being dumb.

Comment: Now let me think laterally.  Define 3-dimensional subspaces $S_1,S_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$ as follows: $S_1 = \{ (r,s,t,0,0):r,s,t \in \mathbb{R} \} $ and $S_2 = \{ (0,0,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} \} $.  Then $S_1 \cap S_2 = span(0,0,1,0,0)$.  Then $S_1$ and $S_2$ correspond to planes in $PG(4,\mathbb{R} )$ that intersect in a point.  Any flaws here?

Comment: No flaws at all: and here you are two planes intersecting in a point. In the same way you can construct two 3D spaces intersecting in anything you want.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!